# Why does my s3 sync command re-upload all files instead of the modified ones?

Tags: amazon-s3

```
aws s3 sync --acl public-read ~/Projects/website/dist/ s3://aws-website-XX --profile XX
```

This re-uploads all files even  if the file exists in S3, with no change on local.

If I zip and upload on website-quickstart S3, it does what I want though.

But I want same behaviour via CLI..Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add some evidence that shows that the files are re-uploaded? For example, if you run the command twice in succession, does it re-upload? Does it also happen if you remove the `--acl` parameter? Please show the logs. Also, what do you mean by "zip and update on website-quickstart S3"? Feel free to Edit your question to add additional details.

Comment: Yes, if I run twice in succession, it does re-upload. I can't remove the acl parameter because I need my files to be public as I am hosting a site.  By 'zip and update', I just mean that dashboard that AWS offers to quickly setup a site on S3 using drag-and-drop system. It's a bootstrap from them with CDN. Also, when I want to upload newly modified files, I don't want to delete files files either, particularly different robots.txt on prod and staging that I have placed manually on the buckets. I have a build command with gulp that deletes and rebuilds dist everytime. Maybe that's why ?

Comment: If you are always re-creating the files, then the source files will have newer timestamps than the destination files. This will cause `aws s3 sync` to re-copy the files. You can use the `--size-only` parameter to only have it copy if the filesize is different.

Comment: BTW, if you want files to be publicly accessible, you can create a bucket policy rather than having to specify it for each individual file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the `--size-only parameter' but does this really work for example in a file I change a word from "John" to "Love". Will that sync the former or later, given the file size will be the same?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the heads up on the bucket policy hint. Does that really impact the speed at which my files are being synced?

Comment: I suggest you experiment to discover the way that sync works. Given that you are re-creating files all the time, you will likely run into issues. The speed of the sync command will not be impacted by the method of providing access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put this here; it's not 100% an answer to OP's question, but for the wayward travelers it might help:

Firstly, I ran into this problem because I have webpack splitting my packages, features, and components each into their own bundle -- AWS started uploading each file on every build, which made development slower and more costly (ran through the free tier in one night of binge-coding).

In my `webpack.config.js` I have a hook on the compiler emit that deploys to my aws dev environment (by calling my `deploy` script); it looks like this:

```
plugins: [
  new BundleTracker({path: __dirname, filename: 'webpack-stats.json'}),
  {
    apply: (compiler) => {
      compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
        exec('npm run deploy', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (stdout) process.stdout.write(stdout);
          if (stderr) process.stderr.write(stderr);
        });
      });
    }
  },
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './dist/template.html'
  }),
],
```

*This was my work-around to make my `--watch true` code auto-deploy in the `active-dev` script below.

My scripts block looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "active-dev": "webpack --mode production --watch true",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "deploy": "npm run deploy-index-bundle && npm run deploy-dist-no_bundles && npm run deploy-bundles",
    "deploy-bundles":"npm run deploy-package-bundles && npm run deploy-feature-bundles && npm run deploy-component-bundles",
    "deploy-dist-no_bundles": "aws s3 sync dist s3://BUCKETNAME --acl public-read --exclude bundles/*",
    "deploy-index-bundle": "aws s3 sync dist s3://BUCKETNAME --acl public-read --exclude * --include bundles/site-index.*",
    "deploy-package-bundles": "aws s3 sync dist s3://BUCKETNAME --exclude * --include bundles/npm.* --acl public-read --size-only",
    "deploy-feature-bundles": "aws s3 sync dist s3://BUCKETNAME --exclude * --include bundles/features.* --acl public-read --size-only",
    "deploy-component-bundles": "aws s3 sync dist s3://BUCKETNAME --exclude * --include bundles/components.* --acl public-read --size-only",
    "deploy-dev": "webpack --mode development && npm run deploy",
    "deploy-prod": "webpack --mode production && npm run deploy"
  },
```

With my `deploy` script I call the four under it; they basically each handle their own bundles and `deploy-dist-no_bundles` takes care of the root/static files

because I'm being really explicit with what I'm uploading `deploy-index-bundle` is used to upload the site-index file created by my entry point in webpack. `main.js` is the default value, so if your site fails because it can't load you can either update the entry point or the `deploy-index-bundle` script.

**@John Rotenstein** above, in the comments, gave the final piece I needed w/ the `--size-only` flag (since webpack is versioning).

Now when I `deploy` I'm only sending the stuff that's changed, and circumventing the webpack versioning that was causing the issue, but if a package does change it'll still be synced based on size.

---

**completely unrelated webpack config for anyone tired of googling**

My `optimization` block uses regex to split out all of the files in my `node_modules`, `components`, and `features` folders

```
optimization: {
  moduleIds: 'hashed',
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
    minSize: 0,
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name(module) {
          const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
          return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
        },
      },
      components: {
        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]components[\\/]/,
        name(module) {
          const componentName = module.context.match(/[\\/]src[\\/]components[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
          return `components.${componentName}`;
        },
      },
      features: {
        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]features[\\/]/,
        name(module) {
          const featuresName = module.context.match(/[\\/]src[\\/]features[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
          return `features.${featuresName}`;
        },
      }
    },
  },
},
```

`html-webpack-plugin` dynamically adds all of the script import tags to my `template.html` (I use a template to static code 3rd party css & bootstrap imports) which produces a `index.html`

My entry block points to the created `index.html`:

```
entry: {
  'site-index':'./src/index.jsx',
},
```

The output block does a bit more magic. I use the `[contenthash]` to version the main build, this causes my site to be refreshed for users after each build, but I intentionally don't use the hash in the `chunkFilename` to address the above issue of re-submitting identical/but differently-versioned code.

```
output: {
    // filename: 'main.js',
    filename: 'main.myAPP.[contenthash].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'bundles/[name].myAPP.bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
},
```

---

Final Note:
The `aws s3 sync` api, specifically the `--include` / `--exclude`, needs a lot of work. I ran into a TON of issues w/ where to or when to put a slash.

I highly recommend running `aws s3 sync` with `--debug` and `--dryrun` to lock in on the right combinations.

- Keep an eye out for double slashes `//`
- The pattern runs on the bucket path too, for my use case I just ignored that (always False for include)
- One include overrides all excludes (that why I start by excluding everything)

Answer (score -1):

If you have more than 1000 files. You should use --page-size options

```
aws s3 sync --acl public-read ~/Projects/website/dist/ s3://aws-website-XX --profile XX --page-size 9999999
```

Comment: `--page-size 1000` is the maximum allowed value, and already is the default value https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: oddly enough It does allow you to do more, but it times out if you try and do to many. I'm running into the same issue as the original poster of how to sync a lot of objects, 7million + objects